# Inserting an Entire Related Record into Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I am currently trying to display a related object record based on a certain criteria, the current code I have is utilizing Iframe which isn't possible to use anymore since it's been patched.

Basically I have a field called **relatedto__c** which displays an ID to a different object if a certain criteria is met, if this criteria is met I'd like a visualforce page to display that relatedto record.

Here is my current attempt which I know isn't possible, but just to give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish here:

```
`<apex:iframe src="http://na94.salesforce.com/{!RESTORE_Touch_Point__c.RelatedTo__c}?isdtp=vw" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>`
```

EDIT: So to give a better visual representation, I'd like this entire page to display on a Visualforce page on a different object:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using <apex:detail> with the related record ID?

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:detail>` might be your best/easiest option here. It won't put the whole page into your page, but it will put the record data with it's basic layout in, and it's one line. Just specify `relatedto__c` as the id parameter and you should be set.